# How to use `\leftmark` as a word in my text?

Tags: sectioning

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
\section{random}
This section is called \leftmark.
\end{document}
```

But only appears the following text:

> This section is called .

Comment: You can not do this, marks are set up in the output routine _after_ all content on the page has been typeset.

Comment: If you don't use a page style that uses the marks, `\sectionmark` does nothing, no no mark is set.

Comment: So, is there no way to place the name inside my text?

Comment: If you label your section several packages have variants of `\ref` that will return the title rather than the section number. so `.. called \nameref{mylabel}` is probably what you want

Comment: And how can I make the label for `\leftmark`?

Comment: No, I mean label the section. \leftmark has no meaning within the body of the page, you do not want it at all.

Comment: Ok, let me get your idea. I need to label the section name... that means to create a code line like this `\label{random}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use marks like that: their value is trustable on only during the output routine.

If your aim is to have the title of the current section available, I suggest

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\gdef\currentsection{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

This section is called \currentsection.

\section{Another section}

This section is called \currentsection.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, my problem was the lack of knowledge to change the command like you did.

Answer (score 2):

marks should never be used within the page. Here you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,nameref}

\begin{document}
\section{random\label{zz}}
This section is called \nameref{zz} it has number \ref{zz}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The is a problem, if I compile for second time it shows me this `??`

Comment: No, like any label reference, the first time you get ?? the second time it resolves the cross reference